# Access Internet Explorer on VM for Selenium tests

Tags: windows, macos, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, virtual-machine

I have a Windows VM setup with Virtualbox on my Mac. The VM is running IE 11. The Selenium tests are running on the Mac. Could someone please tell me how I can access IE on the VM for tests running on the Mac?